# iOS - Japanese PDF text extraction

Tags: ios, pdf

I have Japanese [pdf](http://www.filedropper.com/jpn) with difference array as follows

```
1 = G700;
2 = G12db;
3 = G3a11;
4 = G137f;
5 = G2eee;
6 = G2068;
7 = G4ec5;
8 = G701;
```

How to convert these differences values to Japanese text in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) Author here (a PDF framework for iOS and Android that also does text extraction); we worked a few years on CMap parsing and PDF text extraction and conversion to unicode. For JCK characters you'll need a set of Adobe-provided CMaps that you load, parse and then use to actually extract the unicode.

There's no point in explaining the process again since it's all covered in Adobe Docs and you'll need to implement all edge cases as well to make it work with all documents. Here's a good starting point:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/5094.CJK_CID.pdf
https://blogs.adobe.com/insidepdf/2008/07/text_content_in_pdf_files.html

The CMaps you need can be downloaded from Adobe or various other places:
http://www.pdflib.com/download/resources/cmaps/
(Make sure you check out the respective licenses on these)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through it. :)